# StageWebViewBridge not loading GoogleMaps v3 (Adobe Air)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, stagewebview, stagewebviewbridge

I'm using StageWebViewBridge to load a GoogleMap v3, but i'm having troubles with iOS devices. Sometime it loads, and sometimes it doesn't with no apparent error. Also the "Complete" event gets fired randomly.

I having the same issue reported here:
https://github.com/xperiments/stagewebviewbridge

It looks like the repository is quiet, but maybe someone can give me some directions of how to fix this?

Also everything works OK on Android.

Hope someone can answer.

Comment: no answere, but advice: Have you tried loading Google Maps with the native StageWebview? Does that work? I currently dev only on Android as well, therefore I can not check iOS for that. I too see that google maps is working an android with native StageWebView fine. You should try the native WebView by Adobe. If it fails on iOS that way, you have yourself a bug. Submit it and pray.

Comment: Yes, when i tried using the native StageWebView, the map never loads, so it looks like a bug. Also I have found some forum threads that suggest this. The only option i have left is to create a GoogleMaps ANE for iOS.

Comment: My sympathy. I would be interesting why google maps is not working on iOS though. You could try debug console logs for StageWebView on the iOS device, but you and I know it already: It will not solve the problem.